# Facebook SDK photos returns blank array

Tags: php, facebook

I am using this to retrieve user photos however it always `print_r`'s a blank array:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'XXX',
  'secret' => 'XXX',
  'cookie' => true,
));

if ($facebook->getSession()) {
    try {           
        $profile = $facebook->api('/me/photos');
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($profile);

    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        exit();
    }
}
else {
    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'next' => 'XXX',
        'cancel_url' => 'XXX',
        'req_perms' => 'user_about_me,user_location,user_hometown,user_birthday,user_interests,user_likes,user_photos'
    ));

    echo '<a href="'.$login_url.'">Click here to login</a>';
}
```

If I use:

`$profile = $facebook->api('/me');`

It `print_r`'s an array full of data but not the photo information I am looking for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the facebook session you also receive an access token. You have to use it to make valid api requests. Everything that's not public info require that token. Example of usage:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
// var_dump($session) to see it's content
$facebook->api('/me/photos?access_token=' . $session['access_token']);
```

If doing this you still get empty data, maybe that user does not have any photos.

Good luck!

Comment: The SDK should automatically append the access token so you don't need to worry about that, however I am getting the same blank array when I use this method. On the API site http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/ if I click on 'photos' in the table I can see the JSON data of photos so it's like my app is not authorized to see this despite having "user_photos" set in my "req_perms" when I log in?!

Comment: no, the sdk does not automatically append that token, this is your job. secondly, when you clicked on that link, notice that facebook gave you an access token and added it to your request ;)

Comment: yes I noticed, if I replace the access token param on the fb website with the one from my app it also outputs an empty JSON structure so I think its my app is not authorized, but I don't know why as "user_photos" is set in "req_perms"

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem. My solution :

`$facebook->api('/me/albums?access_token=' . $session['access_token']);`

Hope It's not too late !

Comment: what about photos not in albums?

Answer (score 0):

Try https://graph.facebook.com/$album_id/photos

I am not sure why me/photos does return empty array. Probably it means something else, may be the photos where I am tagged or some other thing. For me too, it returns empty array consistently. but when I try to access graph.facebook.com/$album_id/photos then I get the array of all the photos in that album..

Comment: but you may not always have an album